# Reference data from other rows in a worksheet

Tags: excel-2010

I have a worksheet with several hundred thousand rows![

What I am trying to do is populate the "Item" column 4 with the numerical values underneath the text values in "Raw Data" column 5. While I realize that I can just use =E8 in d2 (which is what I did for this example); however this is not a dynamic solution.

I am looking for something that will look for a Y in "Is Chron" column 1, then count the number of repeating Ys and then count that many rows down in "Raw Data" column 5 to populate the numerical value underneath the text values.

I have pasted the example using vertical bar delimiters.

Would this be a job for vba, or can it be achieved with some excel formula?

```
Is Chron|   Line|   Chron Table|    Item|   Raw Data|
Y|      14| HAR|        400|    14|ADM_DATE_TIME HAR|
Y|      14| HAR|        405|    HAR|
Y|      14| EPT|        18850|  EPT|
Y|      14| EPT|        18851|  EPT|
Y|      14| EPT|        10820|  EPT|
Y|      14| EPT|        10815|  EPT|
N|      14| EPT|            |400|
N|      14| EPT|            |405|
N|      14| EPT|            |18850|
N|      14| EPT|            |18851|
N|      14| EPT|            |10820|
N|      14| EPT|            |10815|
```

Comment: Were you able to use the answer below?

Answer (score 0):

Your table was difficult to read, but you could use the `Offset` function to accomplish what you need and use the `CountIf` function to make it dynamic:

`=OFFSET($D2,COUNTIF($A:$A,"Y"),1)`

If you want the values in column D to be blank if column A does not contain a "Y", modify the code as such:

`=IF($A2="Y",OFFSET($D2,COUNTIF($A:$A,"Y"),1),"")`